# Openxslx and hyperlinks in Excel - Hyperlinks work but don't appear blue-coloured and underlined

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I am using `openxlsx` to generate a massive Excel file with a lot of cells containing internal hyperlinks (i.e. pointing to other locations within the same spreadsheet).

Everything is working fine except for the format of the cells containing these hyperlinks: they are neither blue-coloured nor underlined, so they appear as plain text (but the formula inside is correct and the cell is clickable and points to the right cell).

After having generated the Excel file, I can get the right format for these cells (blue-coloured and underlined) by editing each cell (F2) and validating them (ENTER).

Any idea how to automate this pure format issue?

[EDIT 1]: It seems it comes from a generic limitation of `openxlsx`: there is currently no 'superimpose' formatting option, just a 'replace' one. More explanations are provided in a new question here: [Openxlsx - Is there a superimpose mode for styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73823657/openxlsx-is-there-a-superimpose-mode-for-styles)

[EDIT 2]: My mistake: this issue was not due to "a generic limitation of `openxlsx` and the absence of a 'superimpose' formatting option/parameter", but rather by my mere unability to read the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Not easy without reprex but, given that it sounds like you're managing to generate hyperlinks just without the styling, you might just need to create a style for links and then apply it to the relevant cells:

```
linkstyle <- openxlsx::createStyle(fontColour = "#0000EE", textDecoration = "underline")

openxlsx::addStyle(wb = mywb, sheet = "sheet1", style = linkstyle, rows = 1, cols = 1, stack = TRUE)
```

See `?openxlsx::addStyle`

Comment: Thank you, @lizardburns. I didn't provide any reprex because there is nothing specific in the way I am writing formulas with hyperlinks, it's a pretty generic formatting issue. I already implemented the workaround you suggested but I wanted to ask for a cleaner solution (i.e. not reinventing what already exists).

Comment: One solution can be found in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73823657/openxlsx-is-there-a-superimpose-mode-for-styles