# Openxlsx - Is there a superimpose mode for styles?

Tags: r, openxlsx

I'm trying to use the formatting options of `openxlsx` with `addStyle` and `conditionalFormatting` like I would use them within Excel, i.e. in a superimpose way (e.g. centering a cell doesn't modify the font but just... centers the cell!). Unfortunately it seems `openxlsx` doesn't have this mode (yet): one cannot add a layer of formatting options on another one, at least in a simple way; the new layer simply replaces the former one.

Below are 2 reprexes (it is basically the same governing principle) so that you better understand what I mean.

Reprex #1: By just centering the cell and adding borders to it, the hyperlinks format (blue color) disappears/is replaced by the implicit/default formatting options of the centering format style `ContentsCellsStyle_Centered`:

```
library("openxlsx")

OutputFolder <- file.path(".", "Output")
if(!dir.exists(OutputFolder))   dir.create(OutputFolder)

OutputFile <- file.path(OutputFolder, "Reprex_Openxlsx_Hyperlinks_Spreadsheet.xlsx")

Workbook4Export <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb = Workbook4Export, sheetName = "Tab_1", zoom = 80, gridLines = FALSE)
addWorksheet(wb = Workbook4Export, sheetName = "Tab_2", zoom = 80, gridLines = FALSE)
addWorksheet(wb = Workbook4Export, sheetName = "Tab_3", zoom = 80, gridLines = FALSE)
addWorksheet(wb = Workbook4Export, sheetName = "Tab_4", zoom = 80, gridLines = FALSE)

writeFormula(wb = Workbook4Export, sheet = "Tab_1", startRow = 1, startCol = 1, x = makeHyperlinkString(sheet = "Tab_2", row = 1, col = 1, text = paste0("Link to 'Tab_2'")))
writeFormula(wb = Workbook4Export, sheet = "Tab_1", startRow = 1, startCol = 2, x = makeHyperlinkString(sheet = "Tab_3", row = 1, col = 1, text = paste0("Link to 'Tab_3'")))
writeFormula(wb = Workbook4Export, sheet = "Tab_1", startRow = 1, startCol = 3, x = makeHyperlinkString(sheet = "Tab_4", row = 1, col = 1, text = paste0("Link to 'Tab_4'")))

ContentsCellsStyle_Centered <- createStyle(halign = "center", valign = "center", border = "TopBottomLeftRight")
addStyle(wb = Workbook4Export, sheet = "Tab_1", style = ContentsCellsStyle_Centered, rows = 1, cols = 3)

saveWorkbook(wb = Workbook4Export, file = OutputFile, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Reprex #2: By just applying a conditional format to a series of rows (alternate background colors), the hyperlinks format (blue color) disappears/is replaced by the implicit/default formatting options of the conditional format:

```
library("openxlsx")

OutputFolder <- file.path(".", "Output")
if(!dir.exists(OutputFolder))   dir.create(OutputFolder)

OutputFile <- file.path(OutputFolder, "Reprex_Openxlsx_Is_There_a_Superimpose_Mode.xlsx")

Workbook4Export <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb = Workbook4Export, sheetName = "Tab_1", zoom = 80, gridLines = FALSE)
addWorksheet(wb = Workbook4Export, sheetName = "Tab_2", zoom = 80, gridLines = FALSE)

ContentsCellsStyle_GreyBackground <- createStyle(bgFill = "#BFBFBF")

conditionalFormatting(wb = Workbook4Export, sheet = "Tab_1", cols = 1:5, rows = 1:10, rule = "MOD(ROW(A1), 2) = 0", style = ContentsCellsStyle_GreyBackground, type = "expression")

for(i in 1:10)
{
    writeFormula(wb = Workbook4Export, sheet = "Tab_1", startRow = i, startCol = 1, x = makeHyperlinkString(sheet = "Tab_2", row = 1, col = 1, text = paste0("Link to 'Tab_2'")))
    for(j in 2:5)
    {
        writeData(wb = Workbook4Export, sheet = "Tab_1", x = "Some text", startRow = i, startCol = j)
    }
}

saveWorkbook(wb = Workbook4Export, file = OutputFile, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Do you know whether there is a trick to use the formatting options of `openxlsx` in a superimpose way like I would from within Excel?

[EDIT]: Reprex #3 added below as a solution to the issue from reprex #2 as there is still an issue with the `conditionalFormatting` function. This reprex works as intended.

```
library("openxlsx")

OutputFolder <- file.path(".", "Output")
if(!dir.exists(OutputFolder))   dir.create(OutputFolder)

OutputFile <- file.path(OutputFolder, "Reprex_Openxlsx_Is_There_a_Superimpose_Mode.xlsx")

Workbook4Export <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb = Workbook4Export, sheetName = "Tab_1", zoom = 80, gridLines = FALSE)
addWorksheet(wb = Workbook4Export, sheetName = "Tab_2", zoom = 80, gridLines = FALSE)

ContentsCellsStyle_GreyBackground <- createStyle(fgFill = "#BFBFBF")

#conditionalFormatting(wb = Workbook4Export, sheet = "Tab_1", cols = 1:5, rows = 1:10, rule = "MOD(ROW(A1), 2) = 0", style = ContentsCellsStyle_GreyBackground, type = "expression", stack = TRUE)

for(i in 1:10)
{
    writeFormula(wb = Workbook4Export, sheet = "Tab_1", startRow = i, startCol = 1, x = makeHyperlinkString(sheet = "Tab_2", row = 1, col = 1, text = paste0("Link to 'Tab_2'")))
    for(j in 2:5)
    {
        writeData(wb = Workbook4Export, sheet = "Tab_1", x = "Some text", startRow = i, startCol = j)
    }
    if(i%%2 == 0)   addStyle(wb = Workbook4Export, sheet = "Tab_1", style = ContentsCellsStyle_GreyBackground, rows = i, cols = 1:5, stack = TRUE)
}

saveWorkbook(wb = Workbook4Export, file = OutputFile, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the arguments of `openxlsx::addStyle`. There is an argument `stack` that is set to FALSE per default, which means that applying several styles will always lead to only the last one being "active".

Set this argument to TRUE (`stack = TRUE`) and it should work.

Comment: Any idea how to solve this last issue?

Comment: Not suire if I understand your #2/#3 problem. When you add a link to a cell, it gets the blue link colour, right? But when you add a conditional formatting, the conditional formatting would tak precedence over the link colour? But that is also what Excel does. UNless, of course you choose a conditional format that says "make the font a blue color".

Comment: Reprex #3 is not an issue, rather a solution to an issue exposed in reprex #2.
No, when I use conditional formatting in Excel (exactly the same format as here), it doesn't take precedence over the link color, the link color stays, it is untouched, and I don't need to modify the font color.

Comment: So with #3 you basically posted a solution to #2, is that correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Ok, so then I consider this problem solved.

Comment: I created an issue on Github for the `conditionalFormatting` issue: https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/387